# How to avoid the synchronization when the array need to be copied back to host?

Tags: c#, c++, cuda

What I'm doing is to pass an array from C# to C++ dll. Then I do some calculation in CUDA, and I need to copy the data to the mentioned array. After that I will use it in later steps in C# project.

The problem is after I did some calculation with many kernels and then use cudaMemcpy() to copy data from device to host. The first cudaMemcpy() takes much more time than the similar operations cudaMemcpy() later.

People said the cudaMemcpy() from device to host (not pinned memory) is synchronous. Is that true? Is there any workaround for this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: sync vs. async isn't going to matter.  The first `cudaMemcpy()` takes a long time because the preceding kernels are not finished yet.  The kernels are asynchronous, so they return control to the calling thread before they have completed their work. It's just an artifact of your time measuring process.  You won't be able to "fix" that first `cudaMemcpy` operation.

Comment: @RobertCrovella You're right. It's my misunderstanding about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**People said the cudaMemcpy() from device to host (not pinned memory) is synchronous. Is that true?**

Yes this is true.

**Is there any workaround for this?**

The one thing that could help you is using Cuda Streams. So you overlap the execution with the copying.

**EDIT:**

If you cannot use streams then there are no workarounds possible that I know.

One of the things you can consider is as I mentioned in the comment is to build the whole application on the GPU so that you avoid the memory transfer completely(or may be consider copying very very few bytes to the CPU). This really depends on the type of the application. It may or may not be possible in your case.

Comment: Using cudaMemcpyAsync() with pinned memory and streams to overlap will help but not in this case because I need to copy the array from device to host and return it back to C# code.

Comment: Why wouldn't it help? You can add a `cudaStreamSynchronize` after the `cudaMemcpyAsync` to synchronize the host with the end of the memcopy. Or isn't that a possibility for you?

Comment: @hubs The target array in host is not pinned array, it's a passed array from C# code. That's why I can't use cudaMemcpyAsync().

Comment: True. In that case I am afraid there arent any workarounds. Well we had a similar problem where the memory transfer was taking 80-90% of the total time. We just built everything on the GPU so that there is no wastage of time in memcpy, but it really depends on the application. If its possible try to implement everything on the GPU and copy very minimal(say some bytes) or equal to nothing to the CPU.

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm doing the correct way or not. I'm compute everything on GPU, and on CPU side is to show the result only. Before copying I do big calculation with around 33 streams and more than 20 kernels per stream. Then, I just copy a small array back to host and synchronization happens. Haft of the time just for synchronzing before copying in total running time.

Comment: Well! You can measure the timings for memcpy and kernel + synchronization separately. Then you can identify the bottleneck and solve the problem.

Comment: @SagarMasuti thank you. You help me a lot to make it more clear :)

Comment: @Harry: You can still allocate additional pinned buffer and copy data from buffer to array after `cudaStreamSynchronize` (or waiting on event or doing callback - please note that in the last case there are restrictions on what you can do).